# What is the most "complete" c++ compiler according to the c++ standard as of May 2014?

Tags: c++

Which compiler supports the most c++11 and c++14 features? Is there a list somewhere with this information?

Comment: @NirMH Implementing all features present in the current standard.

Comment: CrystalBall Ltd.'s *ICanC++* not only supports C++14, but also C++17 and C++21. It supports Concepts Heavy, asynchronous functions, virtual templates and UTF-9.

Comment: [Here's a decent feature comparison list for you.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) It shows support for C++11 and C++14 across a number of compilers.

Comment: More seriously, though, you can find conformance and completeness information for both GCC and Clang on the respective vendors' websites.

Comment: Eh, I'll go ahead and post that as an answer, then. I was fairly sure this question was a duplicate, but I can't seem to find anything else on this topic.

Comment: There is no C++14 current standard, so your question is unclear, or at least incompatible with your first comment.

Comment: Note: beyond compiler is Standard Library support. For example even though gcc 4.8.1 supports C++14 fully, the `<regex>` implementation of libstdc++ which is shipped with it... still does not work (it's solved with gcc 4.9 I think).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's a decent feature comparison list for you.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) It shows support for C++11 and C++14 across a number of compilers, including the "big three" (MSVC, GCC, and clang).

Comment: here some tables for gcc: http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html and http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html